# Difference between aerosol and droplet transmission for airborne diseases

Tags: infectious-diseases

I've been doing some pandemic reading and can't find why there is a distinction between transmission by aerosols and by droplets. Some articles give a size cutoff of 5 microns; how is that important?

Aerosols were also mentioned to be either wet (small droplets) or dry (dry remains from an evaporated droplet). Does that mean droplets can evaporate enough to count as an aerosol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Aerosol is a **suspension** of droplets or particles in air. A "suspension" means that the droplets or particles are *suspended* in the air and do not just fall down with gravity. Very tiny droplets can be suspended in this way by the **Brownian motion** of the air molecules: The air molecules move around randomly (their speed indicates the air's temperature) and hit these tiny droplets back and forth and prevent them from falling down as they would normally do because of gravity. But larger droplets are too big, the air's Brownian motion is not powerful enough to keep them suspended against gravity, so larger do fall down and do not create an aerosol.

So, if the coughed-up droplets are big, they will quickly fall down - and as a result the disease will be hard to transmit (the healthy person needs to stand close enough to the infected person to inhale the droplets before they fall down). However, if the droplets are smaller than some size, they form - as I described above - an aerosol. Such an aerosol can be suspended in the air for a long time, which can mean that a person who walks into a room where a person *previously* sneezed will get infected. It can also mean that the aerosol can float around the room, and infect a person standing pretty far away from the source.